# How to improve localhost performance on Ubuntu 18 on the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: apache2, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, localhost

So, I have Ubuntu 18 installed on a Windows laptop. Generally, I've been happy with it, but recently the performance has really taken a hit. My localhost set up is a pretty vanilla Apache/Mysql and handful of useful programming languages. At the moment, I either can't access my locally hosted sites, or it takes a very long time for things to start working. The only errors that I see in the Apache log are `[core:notice] [pid 49] AH00051: child pid 62 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2.` I don't get any errors in the browser, and eventually things work. So, I'm not sure how to proceed with diagnosing and fixing the issue from here. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any strace log?

Comment: Can you point me to a link to how, now sure how?

Comment: Ok, so I followed the hackernoon article on running strace. It provided pages and pages of info. What am I looking for in there? 500 errors?  Not sure what I'm reading and too long to post in the question